# Does docker logging driver keep working when dockerd is down? (with live restore enabled)

Tags: docker, logging

With live restore enabled, docker containers are supposed to continue running even when the docker daemon does down.

During this daemon downtime, does the docker logging driver keep forwarding stdout/stderr from the running containers?

I'm asking b/c I'm unsure if the logging driver depends on the docker daemon process or not.

Answer (score 1):

The docs clued me in, and I was able to verify this behavior.

From [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/#enable-live-restore):

> If the daemon is down for a long time, running containers may fill up
> the FIFO log the daemon normally reads. A full log blocks containers
> from logging more data. The default buffer size is 64K. If the buffers
> fill, you must restart the Docker daemon to flush them.

AFAIK, each container process pipes its logs its corresponding `docker-containerd-shim` process, which then pipes the logs to `dockerd`. If `dockerd` is down, the logs will stay in a buffer and get written to `dockerd` when it is back up. However as the docs specify, if the buffers fill up before the docker daemon is back up, you will start losing any additional logs.